# Apache 2.2.4: problems chroot with modsecurity

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, chroot, mod-security

I've been installed mod_security. If i simply include in the httpd the configuration files of mod_security, it starts normally. Indeed, if i try to add `SecChrootDir /mnt/chr` , httpd will start, but at the request of the page it returns either `404 error` or `The connection was reset` error (Firefox). The httpd error log reports continuously:

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
[Fri Jun 21 23:29:09.672309 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4591:tid 140152074479488] AH00052: child pid 16365 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Fri Jun 21 23:29:09.672396 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4591:tid 140152074479488] AH00052: child pid 16366 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Fri Jun 21 23:29:09.672423 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4591:tid 140152074479488] AH00052: child pid 16367 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Fri Jun 21 23:29:09.672446 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4591:tid 140152074479488] AH00052: child pid 16369 exit signal Aborted (6)
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
[Fri Jun 21 23:29:11.675957 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4591:tid 140152074479488] AH00052: child pid 16488 exit signal Aborted (6)
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
[Fri Jun 21 23:29:12.678989 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4591:tid 140152074479488] AH00052: child pid 16518 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Fri Jun 21 23:29:12.679099 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4591:tid 140152074479488] AH00052: child pid 16519 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

I checked for this file and i have this in `/lib` , `/lib32` and `lib64`.
I also can't understand the 404 error if i have an index page.
How can i fix these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have the 64bit version where you need the 32bit version. See the following:

http://forum.teamspeak.com/showthread.php/40875-libgcc_s-so-1-must-be-installed-for-pthread_cancel-to-work

> I got this to work. Apparently I had the 64-bit version of that
>   library, while the TS server wants the 32-bit one. I obtained the last
>   32-bit rpm for libgcc for Fedora 6 from rpm.pbone.net, then did:
>
> rpm -ivh libgcc-4.1.2-13.fc6.i386.rpm
>
> It installed the 32-bit version side-by-side next to my 64-bit
>   version.

Comment: Thanks. For others who may have this problem: i installed packages from [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=gcc). I needed lib32stdc++6 and gcc-4.8-base (to resolve dependencies). The libs should be copied into the directory of the chrooted dir (for example /chroot/lib/namelib.so.1).